# Clearing a stage in ActionScript 3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, air

I have a weather app programmed in ActionScript 3 and adobe air. When I refresh the page I need the stage to clear and redo the information on the page. The page is furnished through the XML data page. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of what to add using addChild, just do stage.removeChildren() and it will remove everything on the stage. If you want some items to stay on the stage and only remove certain items that you've placed using whatever you've loaded from your xml file, put them in some sort of container movieclip and call the function removeChildren on said movieclip when you want to clear them off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`removeChildren()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChildren()):

```
stage.removeChildren();
```

It is important to note for proper garbage collection that you still must remove any event listeners attached to the children and make sure they are not referenced in any arrays.

Comment: Where would you put the command at? When I refresh the page for the xml to replace its data?